# WPF - binding to a property in ViewModel and to other control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

In my WPF application (using MVVM) I have a `CheckBox` and a `TextBlock`. When the `CheckBox` is checked the value from the `TextBlock` will be saved. There is a binding from both controls to my `ViewModel`. Below simplified XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Label>Add to list</Label>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=AddItem}"></CheckBox>
    <Label>Gross amount:</Label>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Amount}"></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Now I would like to have the `CheckBox` checked when a user starts typing in the `TextBlock`. I know binding can do that but I already bind to a property in my `ViewModel`. How can I bind to a property in `ViewModel` and to other control?

Comment: So the checkbox should both be a way of saving(to where?) the Amount, and a way of indicating that the user has started typing? Shouldn't the user be able to "save" when he has started typing (the checkbox will already be checked then)? Perhaps you can explain how this is supposed to work for the user?

Comment: To be more precise: the checkbox is bound to a property on the ViewModel. Details are bit more complex but it's not main concern. I have it handled. The issue I'm having trouble with is to have the binding from textBlock to ViewModel and from textBlock to checkBox.

Comment: Let me emphasize that text-input control binding would be triggered once you leave the control, not by per-char input events. So you maybe interested in per-char input event and then set your Boolean flag there.

Comment: @Yury Schkatula: I set UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged so it should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the multibinding. Something like this:

```
<CheckBox Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="191,82,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <CheckBox.IsChecked>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource checkConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="IsChecked"/>
                    <Binding Path="UserStartedTyping"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </CheckBox.IsChecked>   
 </CheckBox>
```

checkConverter is a MultiValueConverter that you need in order to decide what to do with the values you are binding with (such as &&, || etc.).

```
 public class CheckConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (bool)((bool)values[0] || (bool)values[1]);

        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            object[] splitValues = { value, false };
            return splitValues;
        }
    }
```

UserStartedTyping is a property in the ViewModel that would be set to true when KeyDown event is fired.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the AddItem to true when the user starts to change the amount value:

```
private string _amt;

public string Amount
{
    get{return _amt;}
    set
    {
         _amt = value; 
        if(AddItem == false)
            AddItem = true;

        //PropertyChanges here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Ideally I'd prefer to do it all in XAML and keep my ViewModel as simple as possible.